# System.IO.IOException during the build process in VisualStudio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017, hololens

I'm working on a Hololens application using Unity 2018.2.20f1. I'm building the application for UWP from Unity without a problem. However, after opening up the generated solution in the VisualStudio 2017 (Community Edition) and trying to build it, the build process fails with the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command ""D:\Projects\VSProjects\VirtualPrague\Il2CppOutputProject\\IL2CPP\build\il2cpp.exe" --libil2cpp-static --compile-cpp -architecture=x86 -configuration=Release -platform=winrt -outputpath="D:\Projects\VSProjects\VirtualPrague\\build\bin\Win32\Release\GameAssembly.dll" --data-folder="D:\Projects\VSProjects\VirtualPrague\\build\bin\Win32\Release\\" -cachedirectory="D:\Projects\VSProjects\VirtualPrague\\build\obj\il2cppOutputProject\Win32\Release\\" -generatedcppdir="D:\Projects\VSProjects\VirtualPrague\Il2CppOutputProject\\Source" --additional-defines=WINDOWS_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA_10_0 --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA --additional-defines=UNITY_WINRT --additional-defines=PLATFORM_WINRT -dotnetprofile=unityjit -verbose --map-file-parser="D:\Projects\VSProjects\VirtualPrague\Il2CppOutputProject\\IL2CPP\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe"" exited with code -532462766.   Il2CppOutputProject C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   44
```

and

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file 'D:\Projects\VSProjects\VirtualPrague\build\bin\Win32\Release\GameAssembly.lib'  VirtualPrague   D:\Projects\VSProjects\VirtualPrague\VirtualPrague\LINK 1
```

In the output there are multiple exceptions, similar to this one:

```
1>il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDE97.tmp' because it is being used by another process.
1>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
1>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
1>   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
1>   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
1>   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
1>   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
1>   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
1>   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The exceptions are the same but were thrown for different files. I tried to reinstall the Visual Studio and managed to get a build. The next day I turned on the PC and this error was back. I stopped all of the VS instances and processed from the task manager, deleted all of the files from the Temp folder and managed to get a build a couple more times. Then this error came back.

From what I can tell, during the build process, Visual Studio creates some *.tmp files and for some reason thinks that another process is using it.

Any idea why this is happening and how can it be solved?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: So here is what I did so far (this is more of a work around rather then a solution)

1. Uninstall vs and unity
2. Clear the registry with ccleaner and Advanced Uninstaller Pro
3. Install vs and Unity

Every time I want to get a build I,

1. Close all of vs instances
2. Clear Temp folder (C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp)
3. Delete previous vs solution
4. Build from Unity
5. Run vs as Administrator
6. Build and deploy the solution from vs

And it works for the most the time. Also, changing the solution configuration (from debug to release and vice versa) helps sometimes.

Comment: Probablly Visual Studio is not able to release or delete that tmp file, have you tried to run it as Administrator and see if the error gone?

Comment: I tried it just now and I'm still getting pretty much the same error. There is a slight difference, however. I'm having three projects in the solution; Il2CppOutputProject (Windows Store 10.0), Unity Data and Virtual Prague (Universal Windows). Virtual Prague being the main project. Two of them are being built, Il2Cpp and VirtualPrague. In the administrator mode, Il2Cpp is was built without errors, the process failed when trying to build VirtualPrague project. I got the same error as I described in the question.

Comment: I was getting this same error the other day and I deleted all the files in my App folder (the folder that I pick when doing the Build in Unity) and then did another Build in Unity and it fixed the issue.